# Is there any HERE API that can give me speed limit information for Construction Zones?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I looked over many Layers and API's but none of them give speed limit information for Construction Zones.

Although, Traffic API has link Id's for roads that are undergoing construction, there is no speed limit attribute.

Two things that I want to have:

1. Link_ID( Construction Zones)
2. Speed Limit (Correspond to Construction Zone).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such information (temporary speed limits) available for Construction Zones, through HERE APIs.